# How to change JPA / hibernate to delete based on ID instead of object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is the JPA setup I am using.  I am able to delete objects as expected, however I need to provide an entire object. While I do not mind doing this I do not feel that it is best practice.  Is there a way, similar to the findByProductId(int productsId) function that I can use for deleting product that is a native part of JPA?

DAO

```
 void delete(Products productToDelete);
```

DAOimpl

```
@Transactional
public void  delete(Products productToDelete){
    productsManager.delete(productToDelete);
}
```

Manager

```
@Resource
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface ProductsManager extends JpaRepository<Products,Integer> {
    Products findByProductId(int productsId);
    List findAll();
}
```

Here is the test

```
@Test
public void delete() throws Exception{
    Products productToCreate = new Products();
    productToCreate.setProductName("Test Product");
    productsDao.createProduct(productToCreate);
    List loaded = productsDao.findAll();
    System.out.println("Product: " + loaded);
    assertNotNull(loaded);
    productsDao.delete(productsDao.getProductsById(1));
    List loadedTwo = productsDao.findAll();
    System.out.println("Product After Del: " + loadedTwo);
    assertEquals(loadedTwo.size(),0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, your `ProductsManager` extends `JpaRepository` (I guess the one from Spring Data JPA), so it inherits a delete method receiving an id (declared in `CrudRepository`):

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    ...
    void delete(ID id);
    ...
}
```

Just expose that method in your DAO interface.

Comment: how would I expose that in my DAO?

Comment: Assuming that the id of `Products` is `Long`, add a `void delete(Long id)` method to the `DAO` interface, and implement it in `DAOimpl` by simply calling `productsManager.delete(id);`